# error "argument of type 'module' is not iterable'

Tags: python, list, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

```
def clean_text (text):
    '''Text Preprocessing '''

    # Convert words to lower case 
    text = text.lower()

    #Expand contractions
    if True:
        text = text.split()
    new_text= []
    for word in text:
            if word in contractions:
                new_text.append(contractions [word])
            else:
                new_text.append(word)
                text = "".join(new_text)
  
    # Format words and remove unwanted characters
    text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/[\r\n],"[\r\n]"', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE) 
    text = re.sub(r'\<a href', ' ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'&amp;', '', text)
    text- re.sub(r'[_"\-;%()|+&=*%.,!?:#$@\[\]/]',' ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'<br />', ' ', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\'', ' ', text)

    #remove stopwords
    if remove_stopwords:
     text = text.split()
     stops = set(stopwords.words ("english"))
     text = [w for w in text if not w in stops]
     text = "" .join(text)

    # Tokenize each word
    text = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(text)
    text = nltk.TreebankWordTokenizer().tokenize(text)
    text = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(text)

    #Lemmatize each token
    lemm = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
    text = list(map(lambda word:list(map(lemm.lemmatize, word)), text))

    return text
```

when I run the above code it runs without an issue.
but when I run the below code using the above def it shows `"argument of type 'module' is not iterable'`

```
sentences_train = list(map(clean_text, sentences_train))
```

I have attached an image of the error for reference.
[image]

I have tried different ways to solve this but it make the error worse. if someone can help me with this and tell me why this occurs it would be really nice. thank you!
any suggestions will be considered.

Comment: Have you ever imported a module called `contractions`?

Comment: yes, I have cus It gave me an error earlier.

Comment: Your code expects `contractions` to be a dictionary, but it is actually a module. You probably did `import contractions` or `import <something> as contractions` earlier.

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). Notice also that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should noty be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be caused by the `contractions`. I don't know how you created the `contractions` but keep in mind that you can only do `if word in contractions:` if the `contractions` is a list of words like
`contractions = ["abc", "xyz", "123"]`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a miss match with your import of `contradictions` and what you actually want to iterate over to check if `word` is in something (Without a complete example difficult to say). See example below for the same error. The solution would be to use `contradictions.[something iterable from this module]`

```py
import os

sent = ['1', '2', '3']
something_it = ['2']

def return_str(s):
    # if s in something_it: # <- something like this
    if s in os:
        return 'x'
    else:
        return s

another_list = list(map(return_str, sent))
print(another_list)
```

Comment: that was for demonstrating the cause of the error. Remove comment from the `if s in something_it` line and put one before the `if s in os`. If you have `import contradictions` (similar to os), then it will fail, because the module is not iterable. You want to use `if word in contradictions.something_it`. What something it means, depends on your library, which is not shown in your example.